# How to configure gtm to track OrderPlacedEvent in SAP-Spartacus?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am using Spartacus 4.2 and i am tracking a bunch of events via GTM.
I have configured gtm to track some custom and standard events but when i try to add the OrderPlacedEvent i get the following error:

```
Type 'TmsConfig' has no properties in common with type 'Config'
```

The import for OrderPlacedEvent looks like this:

```
import { OrderPlacedEvent } from '@spartacus/checkout/root';
```

GTM-Configuration:

```
    provideConfig({
        tagManager: {
            gtm: {
                dynamicConfiguration: true,
                // TODO: Add events for tracking here
                events: [
                    NavigationEvent,
                    OrderPlacedEvent,
                    //... (custom Events)
                ],
                debug: true,
            },
        },
    } as TmsConfig),
```

Does anybody know what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced a similar problem. The reason was that some feature module was referenced before the `@spartacus/core` and it messed up the Config type augmentation.

You need to check if some feature module doesn't get imported before `@spartacus/core`. For instance in app.module.ts.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. The OrderPlacedEvent was imported before provideConfig and that was causing the error!